# WPF ListBox showing empty row created by DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, listbox

I have both `DataGrid` and `Listbox` binded to the same `ObservableCollection`:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
CntGrid.ItemsSource = contacts;
CntListBox.ItemsSource = contacts;
```

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="CntGrid" 
IsReadOnly="False"
CanUserAddRows="True"
CanUserDeleteRows="True"/>

<ListBox x:Name="CntListBox"/>
```

The problem is `DataGrid` allowing adding items (I want to keep this functionality) causes `ListBox` to display an empty row aswell. I don't want my `ListBox` to display this empty row at the end.

Can I somehow modify my `ListBox` to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hide the {NewItemPlaceholder} item in your ListBox:

```
            <ListBox x:Name="CntListBox">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
                                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty row in DataGrid is a NewItemPlaceholder. It has different type from Contact. So I suggest to use a converter to hide it in ListBox:

```
public class ObjectTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var t = parameter as Type;
        if (value == null || t == null)
            return false;

        return t.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

use that converter in ListBoxItem Style to check the type of item and hide them if type doesn't match:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ObjectTypeConverter x:Key="tc"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="CntListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource tc}, ConverterParameter={x:Type local:Contact}}" 
                             Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```